# Testing javascript code for crossbrowser issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing

In my web applications I need to test my javascript code for crossbrowser issues. Some clients are complaining about javascript errors. The most probably reason is different browsers they use because it's hard to reproduce on the developer machines. Are there tools that do automated testing and report issues for javascript?

Comment: While I'm not aware of any particular tools for such tests (I'd imagine that would be a beast, what with so many browsers and different versions of each browser... and different platforms), I'd suggest maybe looking into a library like jQuery or MooTools or EXTJS, all of which do make efforts to try and make sure that their code is as cross-browser as possible.  You also have a community to turn to to ask whether or not a specific method is fully cross-browser, whereas you don't quite have that when you roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [TestSwarm](http://www.testswarm.com/) Haven't used it myself, though, so don't have much to say about its quality and effectiveness.

Comment: seems very impressive tool written by John Resig